# How do you format in code AxisLabel for DependentRangeAxis? 

Tags: wpf, apache-axis, charts, wpftoolkit

I cannot get the axis to format as currency, any idea?

What am I doing wrong?  I need to be able to change the formatting on the fly and for this test I wanted to set it as currency for the Y axis on the scale of values.

Anyone?

Thanks...

```
    var columnSeries = new ColumnSeries
                                 {   Title = reportProcedureNode.Value,
                                     IndependentValuePath = "PrimaryKey",
                                     DependentValuePath = "Value",
                                     IndependentAxis = new CategoryAxis { Orientation = AxisOrientation.X, ShowGridLines = false, Location = AxisLocation.Bottom},
                                     DependentRangeAxis = new LinearAxis(){Orientation = AxisOrientation.Y, ShowGridLines = false}
                                 };

        var labelStyle = new Style(typeof(AxisLabel));
        labelStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(AxisLabel.StringFormatProperty, "{}{0:C0}"));

        var axis = (LinearAxis)columnSeries.DependentRangeAxis;
        axis.AxisLabelStyle = labelStyle;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my WPF4 version of the charting toolkit, your code crashes.  I needed to change:

```
labelStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(AxisLabel.StringFormatProperty, "{}{0:C0}"));
```

to:

```
labelStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(AxisLabel.StringFormatProperty, "{0:C0}"));
```

That is, remove the `{}`.  The `{}` comes from markup extension syntax:

- [{} Escape Sequence / Markup Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744986.aspx)

and is only needed when being parsed by XAML as a markup extension inside `"{...}"`.

Since you are setting the property directly, no markup extension is involved and including it prevents the real currency format from being seen.